# How to reduce time taken to import package/library in python

Tags: python, time, import, package, reduce

I'm currently working on a NLP use case where I use bert sentence embeddings to compute cosine similarity between 2 sentences. For converting the sentence to bert embeddings the package 'from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer' is needed which is taking a lot of time to load. Is there any way I can reduce the load time of this package or reuse this without loading every time I execute the python script.

```
import time

start = time.time()
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

The above package takes 5 seconds to load, can I reuse this package without importing every time

Comment: You can only import it once in your program, and not everytime.